# Inuyasha fanfic - Naraku is Kagome's father and abuses her. Toga is her teacher and her mate

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, inuyasha

I am looking for an *Inuyasha* fanfic where Naraku is Kagome's dad, and he abuses her. She goes to a new school where toga is the teacher, and he is her mate. He gives a spray to her to get rid of her scent, caused by using her powers to heal herself.

Comment: no toga as in inuyasha and shesshomarus dad. he's called toga in this story

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)